# Is there a graph coloring algorithm where limits can be placed on number of vertices per color

Tags: algorithm, graph, colors, np, graph-coloring

I understand that graph coloring is a NP-complete problem. I was wondering if adding a restriction on the number of vertices that can have a given color makes the problem simpler? I can't seem to find any algorithm which does this. For example if I have a graph, I'd like to say "what is the smallest coloring of this graph such that each color has at most 3 vertices", or if it simplifies the problem "is there a way to color this graph with 4 colors such that each color has at most 3 vertices"?

Thanks!

Comment: As someone fighting r600g bank_swizzle scheduling, which puts just that constraint, I would not say it simplifies things, rather one more problem for me to solve. Thx for asking the question though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is still NP-complete by a simple reduction from the original graph coloring problem: a graph with n nodes is k-colorable if and only if the graph can be colored with k colors and no color is assigned to more than n nodes.  In other words, the general version of the problem you're phrasing has graph coloring as a special case, and so it will still be NP-hard.

Hope this helps!

Comment: do you mean np-complete when you said that the problem will still be np-hard?

Comment: @Calpis NP-hard should be correct because the reduction implies that this is `at least` as difficult as the standard graph coloring problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that looking for the chromatic number of a graph given the restriction that a *k-coloring* exists can be easily added to an exact DSATUR based algorithm [[Randall-Brown 72]](http://gcs1.googlecode.com/svn-history/r28/trunk/Recursos/BrownRandall.pdf) [[San Segundo 11]](http://oa.upm.es/11802/2/INVE_MEM_2011_107285.pdf) and prune the search space when one vertex has to be assgined color *k*. In any case the problem remains in NP.